# Recursively append the first element of the list to the rest of a list

Tags: list, recursion, scheme, shift

I am quite new to scheme and I want to take a list such as (1 2 3 4) and send it to a function that will return (4 1 2 3). A second run would return (3 4 1 2) and so on creating a right shifted list with each call to the function.

The first way I figured out to solve this problem is to recursively swap the first and last values of the list. So in scheme I would append the car of the list with the cdr of the list and send the cdr of the list back to my function recursively until only one last swap can be made.

However I am not great with creating recursive functions and I'm having trouble doing it in a new language for me such as scheme. This is what I have tried so far to give an idea of where I want to head.

```
(define (rShift lst)
  (if (null? lst)
      '()
      (append (cdr lst (car lst))(rShift (cdr lst)))))
```

Comment: You didn't test the code. That `(cdr lst (car lst))` part won't even compile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best you can do is take a look at the documentation of your interpreter to see what list functions are available, and construct a solution using them. For example, in Racket using the [list procedures](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html) will accomplish a straightforward solution:

```
(define (rShift lst)
  (cons                             ; stick together the solution
   (last lst)                       ; pick the last item
   (take lst (sub1 (length lst))))) ; pick all items except the last one
```

Let's give it a try:

```
(rShift '(1 2 3 4))
=> '(4 1 2 3)

(rShift (rShift '(1 2 3 4)))
=> '(3 4 1 2)
```

There are countless ways to solve this problem, I'll leave it to you to find the one that best suits your needs, but remember - always try to solve a problem in terms of the building blocks already at your disposal, and don't reinvent the wheel. Just for fun, here's another way, using `reverse`:

```
(define (rShift lst)
  (let ((rev (reverse lst)))
    (cons (car rev)
          (reverse (cdr rev)))))
```

Comment: Thanks, it becomes easier as I learn more of the functionality scheme has already built into it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are intent on doing a recursive solution, then you need to ask yourself "what part of the problem can a solve that leaves an identical but smaller part of the problem remaining" and "how do I end the recursion".

For your problem you end the recursion when you have the last element which you then use to add to the front of the list.  The problem is that recursing with 'right-shift' can't be sufficient because you need to keep around the list in order to put the last element on its front.

So:

```
(define (right-shift list)
  (if (null? list)
      '()
      (let shifting ((list list) (result '()))
        (if (null? (cdr list))
            (cons (car list) (reverse result))
            (shifting (cdr list) (cons (car list) result))))))
;; Hey look, it compiles... gosh I love interactive languages.

;; ... and works.
> (right-shift '(1 2 3 4))
(4 1 2 3)
> (right-shift (right-shift '(1 2 3 4)))
(3 4 1 2)
```

Comment: It's not a good habit to call your parameter *list* in single-namespace land.

Comment: Or it is part of the beauty of Scheme.  When one understands the lexical environment; one understands everything.